# Colour shift car paint / Chameleon car paint

Tags: materials, color

How would I achieve a material effect like this ? Colour changes depending on the angle from Purple, Blue and orange. [image]

I have no idea how to approach this since I am not familiar with materials. I would also like the material to have a very subtle shimmer to it / Glitter effect. No fussed about what renderer is used.

Thanks
Etienne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this. Reflection works (as a coordinate) on it's own, but I feel it looks better when the vectors are combined with the Window vectors.

[image: PaintJob]

The "glitter" effect, you can get by using a White Noise texture as the metallic factor. I added the Voronai Texture, because it's a trick to make it so the White Noise isn't "infinitely zoomable". It also allows you to change the randomness of the shapes. I added the MixRGB to mix it with white to bring the whole texture back closer to "pure metallic" (100% white).

[image: PaintJob2]

Comment: Perfect thank you!